# Add user token to Dialogflow df-messenger from browser

Tags: webhooks, messenger, dialogflow-cx

I want to be able to add a user's token when using the Dialogflow messenger chatbot

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger-cx/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
<df-messenger
  df-cx="true"
  location="us-central1"
  chat-title="first test4"
  agent-id="AGENTID"
  language-code="en"
></df-messenger>
```

I tried the following

```
const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
dfMessenger.setAttribute("user-id","ANYTHING");
```

but it is not sent to my webhook

Any idea how I can pass data from my browser to the webhook request body sent by the messenger?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

`dfMessenger.setAttribute("user-id","6666666666666");`

Print the request body in webhook and see
`{'payload': {'userId': '6666666666666'}}`

Refer this: [Google Cloud Docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#html-customize)